"GaxiosError: Login Required - Google OAuth2 Token Expiry Handling in Node.js Gmail API Integration
I am trying to access my gmail , so that i can calculate the money that i spent on food from this place using receipts that they sent me , i followed all steps on Node js quickstart page and was even able to access labels the first time i logged in , after which i kept running into this Login Required error
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");
const process = require("process");
const { authenticate } = require("@google-cloud/local-auth");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "token.json");
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "credentials.json");

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAuth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
  const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  const keys = JSON.parse(content);
  const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    type: "authorized_user",
    client_id: key.client_id,
    client_secret: key.client_secret,
    refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
  });
  await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
const authorize = async () => {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */


const listLabels = async (auth) => {
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
  const res = await gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: "me",
  });
  const labels = res.data.labels;
  if (!labels || labels.length === 0) {
    console.log("No labels found.");
    return;
  }
  return labels;
};

module.exports = { authorize , listLabels};


app.get("/getLabels", (req, res) => {
  console.log(`/getLabels hit with a get request \n`);
  authorize()
    .then(async () => {
      const labels = await listLabels();

      res.status(200).json(labels);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err, "some err happened"));
});

GaxiosError: Login Required.
    at Gaxios._request (D:\YummpysBill\server\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:140:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async listLabels (D:\YummpysBill\server\utils\gmailConfig.js:77:15)
    at async D:\YummpysBill\server\index.js:18:22 {
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels',
      method: 'GET',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
      headers: [Object],
      params: {},
      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
      retry: true,
      responseType: 'json',
      retryConfig: [Object]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Sun, 24 Nov 2024 07:41:13 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    request: {
      responseURL: 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels'
    }
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels',
    method: 'GET',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/6.0.4 gl-node/20.18.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/6.0.4 (gzip)',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    params: {},
    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
    retry: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  code: 401,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Login Required.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'required',
      location: 'Authorization',
      locationType: 'header'
    }
  ]
} some err happened



your not sending an authorization header with a bearer token.
